# Get data from server and pass values ​to sub components in React (useEffect, useFetch..)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jwt

In order to receive a value from the server and pass it to the subcomponent, useLayoutEffect is used. By the way, useLayoutEffect is executed after the screen is all drawn.
Passing values is difficult because of the order of execution.

Q1. I want to run useLayoutEffect before rendering, or know another way.
Is there any way you can recommend?

Q2. At the bottom of the `ApiServiece.js` code, there is json as the return value for the response. But when I output json, `promise[{pending}]` is output. What is wrong?

I'm studying on my own, so I'm desperate for help. Any comments are welcome, so please help.

**Code Structure**

```js
// AdminContainer.js
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useResolvedPath } from "react-router";
import { getAllUserList } from "../service/ApiService";
import DisplayUser from "./DisplayUser";

const AdminContainer = () => {

    const [allUsers, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
    useLayoutEffect (() => {
        setUsers(getAllUserList);
        // console.log(getAllUserList()); // Promise {<pending>}
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {/* {JSON.stringify(allUserList[0])} */}
            {/* {allUserList.map((user, i) => {
                return <DisplayUser inputUser={user} key={i} />
            })} */}

            <DisplayUser inputUser={allUsers} />
        </div>
    )

}

export default AdminContainer;
```

```js
// ApiServiece.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../modules/authentication';
import store from '../modules/store';
import { API_BASE_URL } from "./app-config";
import { resolvePath } from 'react-router';
import { Sync } from '@material-ui/icons';

const ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN";


export function signin(userDTO) {

    console.log(store.getState());

    return call("/auth/signin", "POST", userDTO).then((response) => {
        if (response.token) {
            localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.token);
            localStorage.setItem("SequenceEmail", response.email);
            window.location.href = "/";
        }
    });

}

export function signup(userDTO) {
    return call("/auth/signup", "POST", userDTO);
}

export function call(api, method, request) {

    let headers = new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    });

    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN");
    if (accessToken && accessToken !== null) {
        headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    }

    let options = {
        headers: headers,
        url: API_BASE_URL + api,
        method: method,
    };

    if (request) {
        options.body = JSON.stringify(request);
    }
    return fetch(options.url, options)
        .then((response) =>
            response.json().then((json) => {

                if (!response.ok) {                    
                    return Promise.reject(json);
                }
                return json;
            })
        )
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.status);
            if (error.status === 403) {
                window.location.href = "/login";
            }
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
}


export function getAllUserList() { 
    let result = call("/auth/getAllUerList", "GET"); 
    return result;
}
```

```js
// DisplayUser.js
const DisplayUser = (inputUser) => {

    const userRef = useRef(inputUser);
    const [user, setUser] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setUser(userRef.current.inputUser);
    }, [])

    console.log('setUser isArray:' + Array.isArray(setUser(userRef.current.inputUser)));

    return (
        // <div> {user.username} </div>
        <div> test </div>
    )
}

export default DisplayUser;
```

**CodeSandbox** order of execution [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-rumple-xhzfv?file=/src/AdminContainer.js)

Comment: Using async function in useLayoutEffect is pointless, because useLayoutEffect is supposed to make synchronous mutations on DOM before repaint. Second issue I see is setUsers(fn(): Promise) => it doesn't return array, but a Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing first you are assigning to the `allUsers` variable (which should be a list) a function, which doesn't make sense. You have to first CALL the function (and using the useLayoutEffect you WILL call it before rendering, but the request will resolve asyncronously, so and you will have to populate `allUsers` only when the request is resolved). One solution would be to show a spinner in the meanwhile for example:

```
// AdminContainer.js
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useResolvedPath } from "react-router";
import { getAllUserList } from "../service/ApiService";
import DisplayUser from "./DisplayUser";

const AdminContainer = () => {

    const [allUsers, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [showSpinner, setSpinnerIsShowing] = useState(false)
    
    useLayoutEffect (() => {
        setSpinnerIsShowing(true)
        getAllUserList().
        then(users => setUsers(users))
        .catch(err => /*Handle error*/)
        .finally(()=> setSpinnerIsShowing(false))
    }, []);

    return (
         showSpinner  ? <SomeSpinner /> : <div>
            {/* {JSON.stringify(allUsers[0])} */}
            {/* {allUsers.map((user, i) => {
                return <DisplayUser inputUser={user} key={i} />
            })} */}

            <DisplayUser inputUser={allUsers} />
        </div>
    )

}

export default AdminContainer;
```

Then in ApiService.js I would use an async await syntax to make everything more readable.

The difference is that `async` functions will always return a promise, so you don't need to use the Promise class directly (`throw` will be equivalent to `reject`, while `return` will be the same as `resolve`).

```
export async function call(api, method, request) {

  let headers = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
  });

  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN");
  if (accessToken && accessToken !== null) {
      headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
  }

  let options = {
      headers: headers,
      url: API_BASE_URL + api,
      method: method,
  };

  if (request) {
      options.body = JSON.stringify(request);
  }
  
    const response = await fetch(options.url, options)
    const json = await response.json()
    if (!response.ok) {                    
        const error = new CustomError("Request not OK :C");
        error.customData = json; 
        throw error
    }
    return json;
 
    //console.log(err.status);
    //if (err.status === 403) {
    //    window.location.href = "/login"; <-- Nope: handle this when calling the function
    //}

 
 
}
```

Note the `Custom Error` that you can create to define additional data extending the default javascript `Error` class:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
   constructor(message, customData = {}){
      super(message)
      this.customData = customData
   }

}
```

Also the getUserList function is an asyncronous one:

And you can create an async function in two ways:

with async syntax

```
export async function getAllUserList() { 
    return await call("/auth/getAllUserList", "GET"); 
}
```

with promise sintax:

```
export function getAllUserList() { 
    return new Promise((reject,resolve)=>{
         call("/auth/getAllUserList", "GET")
         .then(res => resolve(res))
         .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
    
}
```

And those two are equivalent.

Let me know in the comments if you need some clarifications :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Antonio Della Fortuna